# Upload file with CURL and oauth2

Tags: curl

I have to develop an API to upload file using Laravel and oauth2. I have tested the api with postman and work fine. I have to write also an curl script. For obtain the token  i use the following  command:

```
curl  http://mysite/oauth/access_token -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=eeee59ddd3ed8ff3843839b&client_secret=aaaa6f8fa93d59c45502c0ae8c4a95b" -X POST
```

and receive

```
{
    "access_token": "45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

After i execute the command:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer 45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45"  -H "Content-Type: multiform/form-data" -F "file=@path_file" -F "access_token=45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45" -F "IdAdvertiser=5555555555" -X POST http://mysite/api/upload
    curl -v -H "access_token: 45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45"  -H "Content-Type: multiform/form-data" -F "file=@path_file" -F "IdAdvertiser=5555555555" -X POST http://mysite/api/upload
    curl -v --request POST  --url http://mysite/api/upload --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' --header 'Authorization: Bearer 45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --form 'file=@path_file' --form access_token=45ac1JvKsRNky25qnGpC28xAJGvckRXEkzq2a45 --form IdAdvertiser=55555555
```

in this case i receive always the same error:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."}
```

Thank's

Comment: probably a typo for the access token parameter (big A in Access? big P in Parameter? hyphen instead of underscore?), double check with the API documentation. ... where is the API documentation?

Comment: i tested but return the same error, thanks

Comment: I solved, i write the following rules in .htaccess:                      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} . 
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]